# Why is the java crypto padding algorithm called PKCS#5?

Tags: java, encryption

As a followup to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11272/can-aes-use-pkcs5-padding, why does the Java spec define the padding algorithm as PKCS#5 when it should actually be PKCS#7? BouncyCastle's implementation defines PKCS#7 as valid. On a technical basis, Java should be saying PKCS#7, since theoretically PKCS#5 is not valid for AES

Comment: To the people trying to close this: It's not opinion based; it's just pretty unlikely that someone who might know the details will find the question.

Comment: They probably names it like that a long time ago and then decided that renaming it isn't worth the trouble.

Comment: At most they should offer PKCS7PADDING as a synonym for PKCS5PADDING. Would it make you happier if the PKCS5 authors went back and created an addendum to PKCS5 that generalized the padding scheme to larger block sizes?

Comment: @AaronDigulla I think a certain point is reached where you say the likelihood of that person turning up is so small that it would be better to close the question and reduce the much higher risk of opinionated answers appearing.

Comment: @DuncanJones: Being unable to answer a question doesn't make it a bad question. In this case, using PKCS#5 with AES might introduce subtle bugs in the code.

Comment: I still think this is a valid question, especially since there are many questions related to AES on how to use padding. I have posted this to the secure-dev mailing list, hopefully will get a response from there

Answer (score 0):

AIUI, PKCS#5 is formally defined only for 64 bit blocks, while the definition of PKCS#7 extends up to 128 bit blocks.  In practice there is no difference in that all implementations I am aware of will handle both block sizes.  The only effective difference is at the name level.

Comment: While interesting, this doesn't appear to answer the question. The OP looks as though he is aware of the distinction between the two padding schemes.